# Merge tables without overwriting existing ones in mysql phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, export

I was having a "coming soon" page with a sign up form. Since a couple of weeks I've switched to another web hosting and continue working on my new site at my new host, but continued to let the visitors sign up at my old host.

Now my have pointed my domain to my new hosting and want to export all new subscribers and import them into the new DB. Some rows might use same ID.

How can I easily export and merge a table from the old DB to the new one? Please note I don't wan't it to overwrite any row that has the same ID, if it does, I want it to add a new row instead.

I've tried exporting my table "wp_csp3_subscribers" from my old DB and imported it in my new one. But get an error saying ID already exists.

Answer (score 7):

If you're using phpMyAdming (based on your tags), you can expand the export options by selecting "Custom - display all possible options" instead of the default "Quick - display only the minimal options".

Under the data dump options, choose "INSERT IGNORE statements", which will tell mySQL to ignore any errors with duplicate primary keys.

Taken from the mySQL documentation on the IGNORE option:

> For example, without IGNORE, a row that duplicates an existing UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY value in the table causes a duplicate-key error and the statement is aborted. With IGNORE, the row still is not inserted, but no error is issued.

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

also, if you have two sql files from a dump, insert one normally, maybe with `Enable foreign key checks` unchecked, then your second file would like to concatenate the data, remove the `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` and `CREATE TABLE` lines in that second file.  Leave only the `LOCK TABLES` table `WRITE;` and `inserts`